# How to support client side paging in the redux async example?

Tags: redux

In this [redux async example](https://github.com/reactjs/redux/tree/master/examples/async), the fetch method displays the items that come back from the reddit api. How can I support client side paging in this example?

The behavior should be that the call should fetch 20 items and then display only 5 and the user should be able to navigate between the page links. It's all client side.

When I was trying to do myself, the problem that I got into was where should I do the filtering so the 5 items from the 20 items are returned?

Comment: I haven't really gone through this link yet, but might be of relevance 
https://github.com/reactjs/redux/blob/ecb1bb453a60408543f5760bba0aa4c767650ba2/examples/real-world/reducers/paginate.js

Answer (score 1):

You can implement client side pagination in the `component` itself based on some `scroll` or `pageChange` event. This way your `redux store` doesn't come in between and your overall `state` is not effected.

Comment: Do you think it's the better option (between store the paginated data into redux store or component state)? Can you tell me why? Actually, I also think it's better to store the data into the component state so when the component is unmounted the data will be deleted.